# How to get CATransform3D from Projection and ModelView matrices?

Tags: opengl-es, calayer, 3d, catransform3d, projection-matrix

all,
I've got an iphone project that draws a 3D model using OpenGL-ES for a given model view matrix and given projection matrix. I needed to replace 3D model with CALayer, so I put values of model view matrix into CATransform3D structure and assigned it to `layer.transform`. It worked well, layer was visible and moved on the screen as expected, but after some time I realized that my layers behavior is not precise enough and I should take projection matrix into account. And then a problem appeared: when I simply concatenate two matrices my layer looks odd (it is very small, about 2 pixels, while it is supposed to be about 300, as it is far far away) or is not visible at all. How can I solve it?

Here is the piece of code:

```
- (void)adjustImageObjectWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSNumber *objectID = [userInfo objectForKey:kObjectIDKey];
    CALayer *layer = [self.imageLayers objectForKey:objectID];
    if (!layer) { return; }

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    NSArray *modelViewMatrix = [userInfo objectForKey:kModelViewMatrixKey];

      // Get raw model view matrix;
    CGFloat *p = (CGFloat *)&transform;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        *p = [[modelViewMatrix objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
        ++p;
    }

      // Rotate around +z for Pi/2 
    transform = CATransform3DConcat(transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0, 0, 1));

      // Project with projection matrix
    transform = CATransform3DConcat(transform, _projectionMatrix);

    layer.transform = transform; 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? I'm trying to do the same thing — convert from OpenGL projection and modelView into a `CATransform3D` to be attached to a `CATransformLayer`.

Answer (score 10):

I recently ran into this exact problem (I was using ARToolKit as well) and I was very disappointed to see that you hadn't figured out the answer.  I imagine you have moved on now but I figured it out and I am posting it for any other lost soul who might come through with this same problem.

The most confusing thing for me was that everyone talks about making a CALayer perspective transform by setting the m34 variable to a small negative number.  Although that does work it is not very informative at all.  What I eventually realized is that the transform works exactly like every other transform, it is a column major transformation matrix for homogenous coordinates.  The only special case is that it must combine the model view and projection matrices, and then scale to the size of the openGL viewport all in one matrix.  I started by trying to use a matrix in the style where m34 is a small negative number as explained in much greater detail [here](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~hegde/cad/lecture/L9_persproj.pdf) but eventually switched to open GL style perspective transforms as explained [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html).  They are in fact [equivalent](http://milen.me/technical/core-animation-3d-model/) to one another they just represent different ways of thinking about the transform.

In our case we are trying to make the CALayer transform exactly replicate an open GL transform.  All that requires is multiplying together the modelview,projection,and scaling matrices and flipping the y axis to account for the fact that the device screen origin is top left and open GL is bottom left.  As long as the layer anchor is at (.5,.5) and its position is exactly in the center of the screen the result will be identical to the open GL's transform

```
void attach_CALayer_to_marker(CATransform3D* transform, Matrix4 modelView, Matrix4 openGL_projection, Vector2 GLViewportSize)
{
//Important: This function assumes that the CA layer has its origin in the 
//exact center of the screen.

Matrix4 flipY = {   1, 0,0,0,
                    0,-1,0,0,
                    0, 0,1,0,
                    0, 0,0,1}; 

//instead of -1 to 1 we want our result to go from -width/2 to width/2, same 
//for height
CGFloat ScreenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
float xscl = GLViewportSize.x/ScreenScale/2;
float yscl = GLViewportSize.y/ScreenScale/2;

//The open GL perspective matrix projects onto a 2x2x2 cube.  To get it onto the
    //device screen it needs to be scaled to the correct size but
//maintaining the aspect ratio specified by the open GL window.
    Matrix4 scalingMatrix = {xscl,0   ,0,0,
                               0,   yscl,0,0,
                               0,   0   ,1,0,
                               0,   0   ,0,1};

//Open GL measures y from the bottom and CALayers measure from the top so at the
//end the entire projection must be flipped over the xz plane.
//When that happens the contents of the CALayer will get flipped upside down.
//To correct for that they are flipped updside down at the very beginning,
//they will then be flipped right side up at the end.

Matrix flipped = MatrixMakeFromProduct(modelView, flipY);
Matrix unscaled = MatrixMakeFromProduct(openGL_projection, flipped);
Matrix scaled = MatrixMakeFromProduct(scalingMatrix, unscaled);

//flip over xz plane to move origin to bottom instead of top
Matrix Final = SiMatrix4MakeFromProduct(flipY, scaled);
*transform = convert_your_matrix_object_to_CATransform3D(Final);
}
```

This function takes the open GLprojection, and openGL view size and uses them to generate the correct transform for the CALayer. The CALayer size should be specified in the units of the open GL scene.  The OpenGL viewport actually contains 4 variables, [xoffset,yoffset,x,y] but the first two are not relevant because the Origin of the CALayer is put in the center of the screen to correspond to the OpenGL 3d Origin.

Just replace Matrix with whatever generic 4x4 column major matrix class you have access to.  Anything will work just make sure you multiply your matrices in the right order. All this is essentially doing is replicating the OpenGL pipeline (minus clipping).

Comment: Thank you for answer, this question bothers me a lot. I'll try your approach and respond.

Comment: I'm using ARToolkit too but i can't figure out how you've set up Matrix4, and Vector2. Is this a struct definition i need? Also, should this go in ARView or can it stay in the ARViewController? I've been trying so hard to make this work :) It looks like you've got it but i can't reproduce without more info.

Comment: @JimTrue Those are just generic matrix structures from a custom matrix library my project used.  If your project isn't already using a matrix library I recommend finding an existing one instead of rolling your own, I believe there are lots of options out there, matrix multiplication is a very common use case

Answer (score 2):

I just got rid of projection matrix and it is the best variant I've got:

```
- (void)adjustTransformationOfLayerWithMarkerId:(NSNumber *)markerId forModelViewMatrix:(NSArray *)modelViewMatrix
{   
    CALayer *layer = [self.imageLayers objectForKey:markerId];

            ...

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;        
    CGFloat *p = (CGFloat *)&transform;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        *p = [[modelViewMatrix objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
        ++p;
    }

    transform.m44 = (transform.m43 > 0) ? transform.m43/kZDistanceWithoutDistortion : 1;

    CGFloat angle = -M_PI_2;
    if (self.delegate.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)      { angle = M_PI; }
    if (self.delegate.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)     { angle = 0; }
    if (self.delegate.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) { angle = M_PI_2; }
    transform = CATransform3DConcat(transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, -1));

    transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeScale(-1, 1, 1), transform);

        // Normalize transformation
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 1.0f / transform.m44;
    transform.m41 = transform.m41 * scaleFactor;
    transform.m42 = transform.m42 * scaleFactor;
    transform.m43 = transform.m43 * scaleFactor;
    transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    transform.m44 = 1;

    BOOL disableAction = YES;

            ...

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:disableAction]; // Disable animation for layer to move faster
    layer.transform = transform;                
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

It wasn't absolutely precise, but it was accurate enough for my purposes. Deflection becomes noticeable when x or y displacement were about screen size.

Comment: Thanks @Zapko. I tried your code with my marker transforms (are you using String SDK?), and I get nothing useful out of it. I guess I need to sit down and work out what the transforms I'm being passed are actually doing by hand.

Comment: Hi, Tony! No, I'm using ARToolKit+. I don't have the link right now, but I'll write here later, about the project that I took as a base. It would be great if you let me know about results you'll get.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/articles/virtual-reality-on-iphone-code-inside) to that augmented reality project

Comment: as far as i can tell, CATransform3D matrices are actually transposed of when compared to OpenGL transform matrices.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me a lot :-)However I did not get the concept, but helped me a lot, can you explain few things what those 4 distortion values and fx, fy, cx cy

Answer (score 1):

Two possible problems:

1) The concatenation order. Classic matrix math is from right to left. So try

```
CATransform3DConcat(_projectionMatrix, transform)
```

, and

2) The value of the projection coefficient is wrong. What are the values you are using?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Eric! Yeah, I've tried different concatenation orders, many of them ) And what do you mean by projection coefficient, I think I'm missing something?

Comment: nevertheless the documentation right order is left to right for the function. i.e. CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DConcat(model, view), projection) will work as expected. reverse-engineered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take into account that layers render into a GL context which already has an ortho projection matrix applied to it?

See the introductory comment in  on Mac; this class is private on iPhone, but the principles are the same.

Also, OpenGL matrices are transposed in-memory compared to CATransform3D. Take that into account, too; while most of the results seem the same, some won't be.

Answer (score 0):

As a direct answer to the question: projection matrices are designed to output something in -1 ... 1 range, while CoreAnimation usually works with pixels. From this troubles come. So to cure the problem you should BEFORE multiplying modelview to projection matrix, decrease your model to fit well in -1 ... 1 range (depending on what you world is you can divide it to bounds.size) and after projection matrix multiplication you can return back to pixels.

So below is a code snippet in Swift (I personally hate Swift, but my customer likes it) I believe it can be understood. It's written for CoreAnimation and ARKit and tested that it works. I hope ARKit matrices can be thought as opengl ones

```
func initCATransform3D(_ t_ : float4x4) -> CATransform3D
{
    let t = t_.transpose //surprise m43 means 4th column 3rd row, thanks to Apple for amazing documenation for CATransform3D and total disregarding standard math with Mij notation
    //surprise: at Apple didn't care about CA & ARKit compatibility so no any easier way to do this
    return CATransform3D(
        m11: CGFloat(t[0][0]), m12: CGFloat(t[1][0]), m13: CGFloat(t[2][0]), m14: CGFloat(t[3][0]),
        m21: CGFloat(t[0][1]), m22: CGFloat(t[1][1]), m23: CGFloat(t[2][1]), m24: CGFloat(t[3][1]),
        m31: CGFloat(t[0][2]), m32: CGFloat(t[1][2]), m33: CGFloat(t[2][2]), m34: CGFloat(t[3][2]),
        m41: CGFloat(t[0][3]), m42: CGFloat(t[1][3]), m43: CGFloat(t[2][3]), m44: CGFloat(t[3][3])
    )
}

override func updateAnchors(frame: ARFrame) {
    for animView in stickerViews {
        guard let anchor = animView.anchor else { continue }

        //100 here to make object smaller... on input it's in pixels, but we want it to be more real.
        //we work in meters at this place
        //surprise: nevertheless the matrices are column-major they are inited in "transposed" form because arrays/columns are written in horizontal direction
        let mx = float4x4(
            [1/Float(100), 0, 0, 0],
            [0, -1/Float(100), 0, 0],    //flip Y axis; it's directed up in 3d world while for CA on iOS it's directed down
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1]
        )

        let simd_atr = anchor.transform * mx //* matrix_scale(1/Float(bounds.size.height), matrix_identity_float4x4)
        var atr = initCATransform3D(simd_atr)   //atr = anchor transform

        let camera = frame.camera
        let view = initCATransform3D(camera.viewMatrix(for: .landscapeRight))
        let proj = initCATransform3D(camera.projectionMatrix(for: .landscapeRight, viewportSize: camera.imageResolution, zNear: 0.01, zFar: 1000))

        //surprise: CATransform3DConcat(a,b) is equal to mathematical b*a, documentation in apple is wrong
        //for fun it's distinct from glsl or opengl multiplication order
        atr = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DConcat(atr, view), proj)
        let norm = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, -0.5, 1)     //on iOS Y axis is directed down, but we flipped it formerly, so return back!
        let shift = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(1, -1, 0)  //we should shift it to another end of projection matrix output before flipping
        let screen_scale = CATransform3DMakeScale(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height, 1)
        atr = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DConcat(atr, shift), norm)
        atr = CATransform3DConcat(atr, CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(frame.displayTransform(for: self.orientation(), viewportSize: bounds.size)));
        atr = CATransform3DConcat(atr, screen_scale)    //scale back to pixels

        //printCATransform(atr)
        //we assume center is in 0,0 i.e. formerly there was animView.layer.center = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
        animView.layer.transform = atr
    }
}
```

P.S. I think for developers who created all the possible mix with Left & Right hand coordinate systems, Y and Z - axis direction, Column major matrices, float & CGFloat incompatibility and lack of CA and ARKit integration a place in hell will be especially hot...