# get CATransform3D from Projection and ModelView matrices

Tags: opengl-es, core-animation, qcar-sdk

[How to get CATransform3D from Projection and ModelView matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045502/how-to-get-catransform3d-from-projection-and-modelview-matrices)

I have browse this question before，the url；but it wasn't absolutely precise; I want to know why it’s not precise；

I find that  the rotate by x--axis and y--axis is opposite（I can't post image）；the Trapezoidal(when rotate the calayer , it's like a Trapezoidal) is opposite，dose calayer rotate is not like opengl？but it's right when rotate by z--axis.

I want get the Angle and then rotate it twice opposite；how to get Angle by the opengl matrices？

I want play movie by QCAR; I can get opengl matrices,and I want to use UIView to playe movie and other(Familiar with the UIView),and make UIview like Texture.

Answer (score 0):

I just post a example on QCAR forum, you can check the detail [here](https://ar.qualcomm.at/content/play-remote-video-image-use-calayer-sample-code)

The idea is simple.

1.I don't use avassetreader to read the video pixel, instead I use AVPlayer and AVPlayerLayer which can play remote video file.

2.I need to convert opengl modelview matrix to CATransform3D so the AVPlayerLayer will attach on the trackable image.Thanks for [Hammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952866/852487) on stackoverflow, he shared an example about how to make this.

3.I tried to render camera background use opengl and AVPlayerLayer at same time, but the performace is not good enough, so I use another calayer to render the camera background. There is a bug in 1.5.8 when getting camera frame, thank for andersfrank the problem was solved here.

I put my code on pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/kmeVZ7jy

There are still some problem need to solve, but I think this is a right approach.

PS. For question 3 in my original post, you can fix it by set

```
        cameraLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

This will fix  the problem that the aspect ratio of the camera image is different with the iphone screen's.

## Update

All the problem are solved, please check my original post on vuforia and pastebin.