# Transforming a Rectangle to an Quadrilateral with CATransform3D and GPUImage

Tags: ios, opengl-es, gpuimage, catransform3d, projection-matrix

I'm trying to transform a rectangle to an quadrilateral and created a `CATransform3D` projection matrix as described by hfossli [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470493/transforming-a-rectangle-image-into-a-quadrilateral-using-a-catransform3d).
The matrix works with a `CALayer` with out problem, but i would like/have to use it with `GPUImage` and the `GPUImageTransformFilter`, which takes a `CATransform3D`.

It doesn't really work.
The scaling doesn't fit, which means my transformed image gets cut of or points are not "stretched" to the position they should be. There are some threads which describe the translation from a `OpenGL` projection to a proper `CATransform3D` projection matrix like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045502/how-to-get-catransform3d-from-projection-and-modelview-matrices).
It involves some scaling and y-flipping.

So I tried to scale and flip in reversed order in the hope to be able to use this `CATransform3D` matrix with the `GPUImageTransformFilter`, but couldn't really get it to work.

Did maybe someone solve this?